# Buscar no Banco de Dados (Mysql) e criar Sitemap em partes (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho o seguinte código para gerar sitemap:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>';
echo'   <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">';

include 'conexao.php';

$sql = mysql_query("select aluno, matricula, aprovacao from faculdade");

while ($string = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){?>

<?php

$dataaprovacao = $string['aprovacao'];
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dataaprovacao));
?>

<url>
<loc>https://site.com.br/<?echo $string['aluno'];?>/<?echo $string['matricula'];?></loc>
<lastmod><?echo $newDate;?></lastmod>
</url>

<?php } ?> 
</urlset>
```

Gostaria de salvar essa resposta em vários arquivos (sitemap1.xml, sitemap2.xml etc.) com 50 mil urls cada. É possível?

Comment: É possível sim. Você pode utilizar as funções `fwrite` ou `file_put_contents` para salvar os dados em um arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que sim. Você pode criar uma arquivo chamado sitemap.php que recebe um $_GET e trabalhar dentro desse arquivo. Depois, basta inserir um código similar a: 
`RewriteRule ^sitemap([0-9]+).xml$ sitemap.php?id=$1` dentro do seu arquivo **.htacess** para ter uma url dinamica personalizada. Em outras palavras, seu sistema receberia **/sitemap1.xml** na URL e seu código interpretaria como **/sitemap.php?id=1**.